# Dynamic Select Menu with form_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form tag form that looks like this

```
  = label_tag 'fund', 'Fund'
  = select_tag :fund_id,
    options_for_select(??????),
    class: 'form-control reports-filter-select',
    include_blank: "-- Select Funds --"

  = label_tag 'scenario', 'Scenario'
  = select_tag :scenario_id,
    options_for_select(?????),
    class: 'form-control reports-filter-select',
    include_blank: "-- Select Scenarios --"

= submit_tag 'Submit',
  class: 'btn btn-primary',
  id: 'create-geodistribution-chart',
  data: { chart_url: reports_geodistributions_states_path(':scenario_id') }
= link_to 'Clear', '', class: 'btn btn-default clear'
```

I want to create a dynamic select box.....where if a user selects a fund all the scenarios  that belongs to that fund will automatically populate on the scenarios select box

what is the best way to go about this

thank you

Answer (score 1):

My proposed solution is to use JS to detect the onchange event of the first select field. Then make an ajax request to get the data for the second field.

Firstly, I'm going to move the second select field into a partial then it can be reloaded following the ajax call later.

```rb
# /app/views/funds/_fund_scenarios.html.erb
<%= collection_select(:geodistribution, :fund_id, scenarios, :id, :name, { :prompt => "-- Select Scenarios --" }, :required => true, :class => "form-control" ) %>
```

Then in our javascript, I'm assuming you are using a library jQuery here for simplicity sake .

```js
// pass selected value to controller and populate scenarios field with results
$(document).on("change", "#fund_id", function(){
    if($(this).val() != "") {
      $.get("/funds/scenarios?fund_id="+$(this).val(), function(data){
        $("#scenario_id").html(data);
      });
    }
});

// vanilla JS alternative
field = document.getElementById("fund_id");
field.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', "/funds/scenarios?fund_id="+field.value, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      document.getElementById("scenario_id").innerHTML(data);
    }
  };

  request.send();
}
```

Then in your funds controller you get the param and make your query. Adapt the @scenarios instance var to match your models.

```rb
def scenarios
  if params[:fund_id].present?
    @scenarios = Scenario.where(fund_id: params[:fund_id])
    render :partial => "fund_scenarios", :locals => { scenarios: @scenarios }
  end
end
```

Don't forget to set your routes for the GET request

```rb
# /config/routes.rb
get "funds/scenarios", controller: "funds", action: "scenarios", as: :fund_scenarios
```

Hopefully you can adapt this to suit your needs.